# Why is gas so cheap when there is so little proven to be left in the world?

Tags: supply-and-demand

Why is natural gas so cheap, regular people can purchase it for their own needs quite handily without breaking an arm and a leg, when there's so little left apparently?

> The world has proven reserves equivalent to 52.3 times its annual consumption. This means it has about 52 years of gas left (at current consumption levels and excluding unproven reserves)

https://www.worldometers.info/gas/

Comment: According to your own source, in 1980, there was only 48 years left (2.585 T / 52.9 B). Yet, 40 years later, we have all of a sudden ~ 52 years left. Moreover, energy intensity (energy needed to produce a unit of output) declines continuously and more and more alternatives become available.

Comment: I am voting to close this as opinion based because "so cheap" is not based on any calculations.

Comment: @Giskard I wasn't aware that "'so cheap'  must be based on any calculations" was a criteria

Comment: @user253751 Well, how cheap should it be, if not "so cheap"?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, natural gas prices are relatively high now by [historical standards](https://tradingeconomics.com/commodity/natural-gas), although that has more to do with Russian invasion and west's energy policy than to do with dwindling natural gas reserves.

First, the proven reserves are just that, proven reserves. They do not represent total amount of natural gas present on the Earth. Historically, amount of natural gas reserves continuously increases over time as humanity finds  new natural gas deposits quicker than it can extract natural gas. As you can see from the graph below, today we have more natural gas reserves than we had previously regardless of the fact that society consumes a lot of natural gas. In all likelihood in 50 years we will have even more proven reserves than we have now. If gas price increases people have more incentive to look for more natural gas.

[image]

Second, the amount of natural gas we can extract depends on the available technology. For example, thanks to fracking (which can be used not just for oil but also natural gas) natural gas can be extracted even from wells that were considered depleted making more natural gas available.

Third, as world's economy gets more and more decarbonized over time it is likely humanity will never actually reach point where all natural gas is extracted from the Earth's crust.

Fourth, even if we were left only with 52 years of natural gas the price would not necessarily just immediately shoot up to some extremely high value. If people would know that the resource is about to run out, producers may try to bring less to the market now in anticipation of future higher price. This would already increase present day prices. However, there is no a priory reason why the price would just suddenly increase by some astronomic value.